# How to concatenate Nextflow process outputs into a single file?

Tags: nextflow

I like to concatenate all output files into a single file. Here is an example:

> Process Headers is sorting and adding headers to all the supplied blastn hits files.

and

> Process Concatenation is supposed to concatenate all the "Process Headers" outputs into a single file.

I've tried `collectFile`. However, Process Concatenation still just produces the first file, and is not concatenating all the files. There is also no error message either.

Please see the script below. Greatly appreciate your suggestions. Thank you.

```
#!/usr/bin/env nextflow

nextflow.enable.dsl=2

params.in = "$PWD/*.tsv"
params.outdir = './'

//sorting blastn hits and adding headers 
process headers {
    tag "${x.baseName}"
    publishDir "${params.outdir}/results", mode:'copy'

    input:
    path(x) 
    
    output:
    path "${x.simpleName}_blast_sort_withHeader.tsv" 

    script:
    """
    sort -k1,1 -k5,5n -k4,4nr -k6,6nr ${x} > ${x.simpleName}_blast_sort.tsv
    awk 'BEGIN{print "qaccver\tsaccver\tpident\tlength\tevalue\tbitscore\tmismatch\tgapopen\tqstart\tqend\tsstart\tsend\tstitle"}1' ${x.simpleName}_blast_sort.tsv > ${x.simpleName}_blast_sort_withHeader.tsv
    """
}

//concatinating sorted blastn files into a single file
process concatenation {

    publishDir "${params.outdir}/results", mode:'copy'

    input:
    path 'tsv'

    output:
    path "concatenatedHits.tsv" 
    
    script:
    """
    cat ${tsv} > concatenatedHits.tsv
    """
}

//workflow definition
workflow {

    Channel.fromPath( params.in ) \
        | headers \
        | collectFile \
        | concatenation \

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know nextflow very well. But the following line rings alarm bells:

`cat ${tsv} > concatenatedHits.tsv`

Every time you run this line, you replace what was previously in `concatenatedHits.tsv` with what is currently in `${tsv}`. This could explain why you're only seeing the output of one result (the last one that was run).

To instead append new content to the end of the existing file, use `>>`.

Comment: Thank you. A data channel with `.collect()` operator together with `>>` output operator resolved the issue!

Comment: Super I'm delighted to hear that!

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried to use `collectFile`, but here is a process than can handle flexible input file numbers:

```
process concatenation {
    publishDir "${params.outdir}/results", mode:'copy'

    input:
    path 'tsv'

    output:
    path "concatenatedHits.tsv" 
    
    script:
    def cat_files = tsv.collect{ "cat $it >> concatenatedHits.tsv" }.join("\n")
    """
    ${cat_files}
    """
}

workflow {
    Channel
      .fromPath( params.in )
      .set{ ch_in }
    headers( ch_in )
    headers
      .out
      .collect()
      .set{ concat_in }
    concatenation( concat_in )
}
```

Untested, and you can ignore the difference in workflow syntax it's just a preference thing for me and a little bulkier than yours.

Comment: Thank you. I have tested your script. It answered my question. I've posted a simplified script below.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest version of the script that answers the question:

```
#!/usr/bin/env nextflow

nextflow.enable.dsl=2

params.in = "$PWD/*.tsv"
params.outdir = './'

//sorting blastn hits 
process headers {
    tag "${x.baseName}"
    publishDir "${params.outdir}/results", mode:'copy'

    input:
    path(x) 
    
    output:
    path "${x.simpleName}_blast_sort.tsv" 

    script:
    """
    sort -k1,1 -k5,5n -k4,4nr -k6,6nr ${x} > ${x.simpleName}_blast_sort.tsv
    
    """
}

//concatinating sorted blastn files into a single file and adding headers
process concatenation {

    publishDir "${params.outdir}/results", mode:'copy'

    input:
    path 'tsv'

    output:
    path "concatenatedHits_withHeaders.tsv" 
    
    script:
    
    """
    cat ${tsv} >> concatenatedHits.tsv
    awk 'BEGIN{print "qaccver\tsaccver\tpident\tlength\tevalue\tbitscore\tmismatch\tgapopen\tqstart\tqend\tsstart\tsend\tstitle"}1' concatenatedHits.tsv > concatenatedHits_withHeaders.tsv
    
    """
}

//workflow definition

workflow {

    Channel.fromPath( params.in ) 
        | headers 
    
    concatenation(headers.out.collect())

}
```